# How to merge unsupervised hierarchical clustering result with the original data

Tags: r, merge, tree, hierarchical-clustering

I carried out an unsupervised hierarchical cluster analysis in R. My data are numbers in 3 columns and around 120,000 rows. I managed to use cut tree and recognised 6 clusters. Now, I need to return these clusters to the original data, i.e. add another column indicating the cluster group (1 of 6). How I can do that?

```r
# Ward's method
hc5 <- hclust(d, method = "ward.D2" )

# Cut tree into 6 groups
sub_grp <- cutree(hc5, k = 6)

# Number of members in each cluster
table(sub_grp)
```

I need that as my data got spatial links, hence I would like to map the clusters back to their location on a map. 
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The variable sub_grp is just a vector of cluster assignments so you can just add it to the data frame:

```
data(iris)                         # Data frame available in base R.
str(iris)
d <- dist(iris[, -5])              # Column 5 is the species name so we drop it
hc5 <- hclust(d, method="ward.D2")
sub_grp <- cutree(hc5, k=3)
str(sub_grp)
iris$grp <- sub_grp
str(iris)
aggregate(iris[, 1:4,], by=list(iris$grp), mean)
xtabs(~grp+Species, iris)
```

The last two commands compute the means by groups for the 4 numeric variables and cross-tabulate the cluster assignments with the known species. You don't actually need to add the cluster assignment to the data frame. R lets you combine variables from different objects as long as they have the same number of rows.